# Import variable that changes after import

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a module that takes care of logging and provides a logger variable to a bunch of other modules:

**log_module.py**

```
my_logger = None

def init_var(program_args):
    my_logger = logging.getLogger(program_args.something)
```

The logger is initially None but will be initialized very early in the program (after all the imports though).

When other modules import the logger, it has not been initialized and thus is `None`

```
from log_module import my_logger
print(my_logger) // None
```

When `my_logger` is changed from within the log_module, it does not affect the imported variable since that resides in the importing module's global namespace.

I could `import log_module` and then write `log_module.my_logger.log("...")` but that would get quite lengthy.

Is there another way to use a variable from a module that will change after it has been imported?

Comment: `from my_base_module import my_variable as my_short_variable_name_here` then `my_short_variable_name_here.do_something()`?

Comment: @muddyfish: The variable would still change after the import, even with a shorter name ;)

Comment: Import the variable when/where you need it; I assume it has been initialized to its properly value by then, so put the import statement at that point.

Comment: @Evert: wouldn't that violate the [Google Python Styleguide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Imports_formatting)? There are also several methods in each module (not a class with an `__init__` method) which use the variable, I would have to import it in each method. Alternatively, I could also notify all modules about the variable but that would involve calls to several dozen modules and doesn't scale nicely

Comment: A really hacky workaround would be to write a wrapper class for `my_variable` or just put it inside a list. You could then always access your variable by `my_variable[0].do_something()` and could change it by `my_variable[0] = Something`. A wrapper object could make this feel even more naturally.

Comment: I'd rather point to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) than the Google Python Styleguide, though the latter agrees (copied) with (from) the former. But overall, since what you're attempting is non-standard, you may need to deviate from some guidelines. Or, in accordance with Amit Shah's answer, think about changing your approach: variables are usually not imported, just because they are, well, variable (ditto for class instances, for example: import the class, not the instance. You import a function, not the result of a function evaluation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be best of changing your approach. 
Perhaps have some class which is a singleton, storing the value of the variable, so that when the variable is actually needed, it is fetched from the class, rather than the import.

Answer (score 1):

When using a logger configured in module A in module B, you simply obtain that logger with the right name, at the point in your program where you need it. Inside module B:

```
logging.getLogger(program_args.something)
```

Don't reimport the logger from module A.

If you don't have access to `program_args.something`, you may want to think up a better name: your logger probably doesn't need to have that much of a flexible name.

Also think about logger namespacing within a package: a logger named `'module.submodule.subsubmodule'` will still pick up the configuration from a logger named `'module'`, for example.