# Calling Function From Another File Does Not Recognise Defined Name

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to python and selenium. I want to call a login function from another file and then continue my test within the same driver. I've managed to write a login function > call it from the other file but when I continue with my test, i get the following error, NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

How can I make this work so I can reference the login function to login and then continue writing code without getting the NameError?

Here is the code

**file1.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def login(context):
    s = Service("C:pythonProject/chromedriver.exe")

    # Starts the chrome driver
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.maximize_window()


def username(context):
    # URL
    url = "https://www.bbc.com"
    driver.get(url)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "user")
    search.send_keys('xxxxx')

    search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass")
    search.send_keys('xxxxx')

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "log_in_button").click()
```

```
file2.py

    from behave import *
    from file1 import *
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    @given(u'sdsd')
    def step_impl(context):
        login(context)
        username(context)
    
    
    @when(u'sdds')
    def step_impl(context):
        search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "headerBar")
```

Comment: Um… `import`?  That’s usually how you use multiple files.

Comment: Sorry I have now formatted the code correctly so you can now see what I have imported.

Comment: We don't wnow what `behave` etc are. Anyway, a saner design is to avoid globals and instead have the caller supply values for all the variables which are not internal to your functions.

Comment: Have you got an example I can try? (sorry,still picking up the syntax and understanding)

Answer (score 0):

Not even `from … import *` can give you access to names added by `global` **after** the import occurs.  (Worse still, if they are reassigned, you’ll still [have the old value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32221123/8586227).)

Just take that as yet another reason not to use that syntax: write

```
import file1

def …:
    search = file1.driver.find_element(By.ID, "headerBar")
```

or better yet have the `file1` functions **return** `driver` rather than storing it in a global at all.